# Can I connect to a SQL Server 2000 instance from SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2000, sql-server-2012, ssms

I would like to update my development machine to SQL Server 2012 but I still manage some (very old) SQL Server 2000 machines. Wil my 2012 SSMS be able to connect to those SQL Server 2000 machines?

SQL Server 2008 R2 works fine (what I have now).

Comment: I *did* try searching for answers to this but my Google-Fu is weak today...

Comment: Yes, you can. I do it every day.

Comment: Don't forget about the port in the connection if you have a side by side installation. For instance: DEV\SQL2000,63030

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, I have done it.  My website http://www.rocketclubs.com is on SQL server 2000 and I updated it last night in full windows 8, SSMS 2012 setup.

Comment: Just to be clear: you *connected* to SQL 2000 from SSMS 2012? Not *upgraded*?

Comment: Yes.  No upgrading anywhere (I don't have the money to do anything like that).

Comment: Note: SQL Server 2012 Profiler does *not* work with SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you absolutely CAN connect to a SQL Server 2000 instance using SSMS 2012 as a client.  I do it every day as I still have 5 SQL Server 2000 instances in my environment that I manage.  However, keep in mind that SSMS will present you with some options based on functions that are available in the version of SSMS you are using, and you may not be able to perform those functions from SSMS due to differences in commands between the versions.

And there are some things that SQL 2k simply doesn't like coming from SSMS.  For example, if you use the GUI to manage permissions for a database role be prepared for SSMS to crash in some circumstances. For that reason it is always a good idea to keep a copy of SQL 2000 Enterprise Manager handy somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I was having "timeout" issue when trying to connect to SQL Server 2000 using Management Studio 2012. Finally the solution for me was to install Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Service Pack 4 - http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=18290

I hope that this solution can be useful for someone having this problem.